# Как правильно завершить приложение libgdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

В примерах к libgdx применяется вызов Gdx.app.exit()
В тоже время в некоторых проектах видел такой вызов Process.killProcess(Process.myPid())

Какой из двух вариантов будет правильным?

Comment: Выход из игры решает система

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proccess.killProccess только на Android работает.
Значит надо использовать Gdx.app.exit()